# Will lots of haptic feedback kill motors?

Tags: joystick, force-feedback

My game centers around joystick oddities, sort of, to make it more interesting.

I've got a cheap $6 joystick that is like a usb PS3 controller. Surprisingly, I find it of great quality, with excellent feedback.

I don't care about it so much, because of the price but I don't want to kill motors in a users expensive joystick.

Basically, it will be running for minutes at a time every once in a while.(Well, not constantly, but almost constantly)

Are these motors really good, and hard to wear down or will I quickly kill them?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You will eventually burn them out if you use them continually for long periods. eventually. If it only cost you 6$ I'm sure that its not really a major investment even if you do ;) There's likely more risk to your hands than the controller...

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to kill users $50 joysticks.Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Succinctly, Running the motors flat out for extended periods of time is probably not recommendable, for the motors, or your hands.   Vibration is achieved by attaching off center weights to the motors, there's usually a couple of different "types" per controller (ps3/360 have two, a smaller weight and a larger weight). Its also worth noting that most people dont really like it when controllers vibrate for extended periods of time, especially frustrating if you have to put the controller down to reach a debugger ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.** Eventually. But it's not something you likely need to worry about.

If the motors are [brushless motors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor), they'll last as long as the ball bearings. A very long time (usually). However, if they're the more common [brush type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushed_DC_electric_motor) motors, they'll be shorter lived (but still a long time!) and get less powerful the more they're used. The quality of the motors is likely to vary greatly. They can work from hundreds of hours of continuous use, to thousands. The motors will most likely last longer than the game will be played (nothing against your game).

You should use the feedback motors as much as you need them to make the game play the way you want it to. Make sure you're not over using them! You can always give the player the option of disabling the feedback, or reducing it. The responsibility of maintaining the hardware is always the user's, give them some choices. If they don't have the choice to disable the feedback, their only option to "save" their controller is to not play your game.

Comment: Perfect, all I wanted to know and then some. Thank you!

Comment: "The responsibility of maintaining the hardware is always the user's" - in a perfect world, yes. But I'm reminded of the Starcraft 2 overheating laptops episode; [guess where the initial vitriol was directed?](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/248415465?page=2) I think devs shouldn't completely ignore issues outside their responsibility.

Comment: I think most of that thread supports that hardware is the user's responsibility (or at least the hardware manufacturer).

Comment: @Byte56 My point is that some users will still blame the developers, even if they are only slightly (if at all) responsible.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no.  That's because they are MEANT to be used.  For example, what's the point of flying a combat flight sim with a haptic controller if it's not basically constantly doing things to give you feedback?  It would be rather pointless if it just twitched every few minutes.